# Deploying to the Cloud for Public Access

Tags: bugs, wolfram-cloud

**Note:** Fixed sometime around the 18th of August 2014.  Bug present from the release of 10.0.0. until then.

---

I wanted to test how a simple deployed program would appear to a non-mathematica user. I did the following, from within a Mathematica notebook:

```
obj = CloudDeploy[FormFunction[{"country" -> "Country"}, Show[#country["Flag"], ImageSize -> 600] &, "SVG"], Permissions -> "Public"]
```

As expected:

```
Options[obj, Permissions] 

{"Owner" -> {"Read", "Write", "Execute"}, "All" -> {"Execute"}}
```

But when I try to access the link (from another machine), it prompts me for a userid and password for the Cloud platform. I tested this several times on different machines, and the result was always the same.

Is this the intended behavior? I thought the idea was that anyone could access a deployed object, without having to sign up for an account (even a free one).

Comment: Adding fuel to the fire; if I create the `CloudObject` and attempt to access it with a different Wolfram Cloud account, I cannot access the form and instead get the input cell in the Programming Cloud interface.  (Not sure how much further I can debug, given that four clicks of Shift-Enter have used up 10% of my monthly allowance of cloud credits...

Answer (score 9):

**Read was only necessary because of a bug. It has now been fixed according to Joel Klein's answer.**

"Execute" doesn't seem to be enough. You also need to give users permission to read:

```
obj = CloudDeploy[
  FormFunction[{"country" -> "Country"}, 
   Show[#country["Flag"], ImageSize -> 600] &, "SVG"], 
  Permissions -> "rx"]
```

**Follow up:** I asked WRI's support this and they said not giving the `Read` capability in this case was intended, and in accordance with the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Permissions.html):

> The setting "Public" allows execution of APIFunction, FormFunction,
>   and related constructs. It allows reading and interaction for notebook
>   and CDF objects. For other objects, it allows reading only.

So there are two different kinds of "public": Some object that are "public" can be accessed by anyone, while some other objects that are public can only be accessed by authorized users. I pointed out that this was confusing and that the docs could do a better job explaining this, and they said they'd pass this feedback on to the developers.

Comment: That did the trick.  Thank you!

Comment: Interesting that "Public" doesn't provide read access.  Perhaps another bug?

Comment: @bobthechemist I think it might be unintended, because as the documentation for `Permissions` shows `Public` usually sets the `Read` permission, but on this particular object it sets the `Execute` permission for some reason. I will report it as a bug and if it gets confirmed I will add the tag.

Comment: The intention is that Permissions->"Public" for CloudDeploy of APIFunction, FormFunction, or Delayed means to set Execute only.  Execute lets you run the code, read would let you peek at the source.  Setting Permissions->"Public" for other kinds of objects typically means "read".

Comment: @JoelKlein But let's say you deploy a form like in this example. What does it matter that other people could theoretically execute the code when they can't even see the form?

Comment: It was a bug that "read" and/or login was required.  All -> "Execute" should allow anyone to access the form without requiring a login.

Answer (score 4):

`Permissions->"Public"` is exactly the right thing to do, you should only need a permission of `All -> "Execute"` for users to access and use a form.

What you saw was a bug that has been fixed.

For APIs, forms, and web computations, the `"Execute"` permission is the one needed to use it (that is to run, or execute), whereas the `"Read"` permission allows you to view the contents, e.g. through `CloudGet`.